# Confused by the source and target keyword in mount system call

Tags: linux, mount, linux-namespaces

I am implementing a container which is cloned with a new namespace including mount, pid, user namespaces, etc. The first step the child does is to mount several important points such as `/proc`, `/sys` and `/tmp` using `mount` system call.

```
if(::mount("proc", "/proc", "proc", 0, NULL)==-1) {
  printf("Failed on mount: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  return -1;
}

if(::mount("sysfs", "/sys", "sysfs", 0, NULL)==-1) {
  printf("Failed on mount: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  return -1;
}

if(::mount("tmp", "/tmp", "tmpfs", 0, NULL)==-1) {
  printf("Failed on mount: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  return -1;
}
```

However, I am a bit confused by the `source` field in the argument list passed to `mount`.

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
          const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
          const void *data);
```

What does the source mean exactly? For example, mounting `/tmp` seems have nothing to do with the source char string. I can still see a new `/tmp` folder created under the new namespace even using `::mount(nullptr, "/tmp", "tmpfs", 0, NULL)`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is just supposed to match the argument such as those provided in your `/etc/fstab` file. For instance, on my fstab I have:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
...
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
```

But those examples are a bit different, because of their nature. Indeed, both proc and sysfs are not general filesystem. Hence, if you would have mounted a hard drive, the source would be more straightforward, being `/dev/sda1` for instance.

And because you're implementing an isolation on top of namespaces, beware if the container calls `umount` on `/proc` for instance. It might reveal the host's proc, thus, breaking the isolation.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Aif`s answer: according to the [mount manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man2/mount.2.html):

> mount()  attaches  the filesystem specified by source (which is often a
>          pathname referring to a device, but can  also  be  the  pathname  of  a
>          directory  or  file, or a dummy string) to the location (a directory or
>          file) specified by the pathname in target.

In the case of `tmpfs`, it is very much a dummy string. You are simply creating *a* temporary file system. `tmpfs` is stored in volatile memory and is temporary, not really having a source.

For other filesystem types, `source` will be very important, specifying which filesystem you are mounting to that directory, e.g. `/dev/sda1` or what have you.